# Migration of tables to database

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp, localhost

[screenshot of Error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbtpj.png)>Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'hiring' (SQL: insert into `hirings` (`name`, `email`, `subject`, `message`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , 2018-01-24 19:31:19, 2018-01-24 19:31:19))

Portfolio is my database name

In `.env` file is the same, my model name is `hiring`, my table name is `create_hiring_table` everything looks fine to me. Anything I am missing?

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:9ALfdXT6SdgOkZ3gFVCExTFY4z/8yzOfbuCuB7dA1h0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=portfolio
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

my model name hiring.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class hiring extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
protected $fillable = [
    'name','email','subject','message'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

my controller named mainController

```
<?php    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\hiring;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class mainController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('main.main');
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        $hiring = new hiring;

        $hiring-> name = $request->name;
        $hiring-> email = $request->email;
        $hiring-> subject = $request->subject;
        $hiring-> message = $request->message;

        $hiring-> save();
        return view('main.main');
    }
}
```

My table is following named create_hiring_table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateHiringsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hiring', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('subject');
            $table->string('message');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('hiring');
    }
}
```

This is config/databse.php

```
<?php

 return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

];
```

Comment: You are using the 'hiring' database, rather than portfolio.

Comment: Post your db connection string ( if posting .env remember to hide passwords)

Comment: No i am not using hiring db its name is portfolio DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=portfolio
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: `Unknown database 'hiring'` Are you 100% certain on that?

Comment: Post your `.env` file then.. also, make sure you're not mixing up `.env` and `.env.example`

Comment: yes wait let me give you screenshot of phpmyadmin

Comment: phpmyadmin will just show that the database 'portfolio' exists, not that you are using that database.

Comment: Please show `config/database.php` and the model.

Comment: "my table name is create_hiring_table" vs "insert into hirings ...".

Comment: i have not changed anything on database.php @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: @HuwaizaTahir please show the model and the query and the migration then.

Comment: i am going to post model and controller on my question kindly look at it @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: @HuwaizaTahir it's weird because the settings are ok if you didn't modify the `config/database.php` file. Try to clear config cache with `php artisan config:clear`. If the error after this is different, please post a new one.

Comment: Still nothing anyways i am going to post database.php too @AlexeyMezenin   i knew i will die like this

Comment: @HuwaizaTahir temporarily change the line in `database.php` to `'database' => dd(env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge')),` and run the query. What output do you see?

Comment: yeah it changed but just written 'hiring'  now on the page @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: @HuwaizaTahir this means it's `hiring` in the `.env` file. Please check this file again. Make sure it's the right one. This file is in the same project's root and called `.env` and not `.env.example` or something different. In some OS this file will be hidden and you may be editing some `.env.txt` with a hidden extension or something.

Comment: 'hiring' is written does that mean my database name is still hiring @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It is working all good in my other projects but this is'nt the problem .env is all good at least my question is good give me one score atleast

Comment: @HuwaizaTahir I've described everything in my previous comment. The problem is for 100% in the `.env`. Please check everything I've described.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i have as you said still nothing but i'll find out the bug and let you know

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i found the most silly mistake ever in web.php the rout should be Route::post('/main', 'mainController@store'); instead of Route::get('/main', 'mainController@store');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the mistake ever in web.php the rout should be Route::post('/main', 'mainController@store'); instead of Route::get('/main', 'mainController@store');

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem since `dd(env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'))` in the `config/database.php` returns `hiring`.

Comment: i know but may be it is returning the value of table that is connecting with database

Comment: No, it's not. It returns DB name defined in the `.env`.

Comment: my page is showing also table is not created by migrate command you are right so it's still problem in env

Answer (score 0):

just add `protected $table = 'hiring';`

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class hiring extends Model
{
use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'hiring'; 

protected $fillable = [
    'name','email','subject','message'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```